# Organizing legend symbols in more than one column using QGIS

Tags: qgis, legend, layout-manager

Is there a method to organize the legend symbols in more than on column in QGIS layout manager?

For the same label I want to have a symbol that represents the actual situation and one that represents the planned situation (like the attached image) without the use of the another software

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use QGIS 3.16, you can change the symbol selecting Legend items,then you have to unchek  auto update, this will give you more control over the legend items.

Now you can do double click on the symbol that you want change,to choose personal symbol and create a new symbol with two items side by side, working with offset